# zeros of a bijective holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis, roots

Let $V,W \subset \mathbb{C}$ be open sets. Let $f\colon V \to W$ be a bijective holmorphic map. Then, the set $Z:= \left\{v\in V \colon f'(v)=0\right\}$ is empty.

I know that $f$ is a homeomorphism and that $Z$ is a discrete closed set in $W$. but I'm not sure if $Z$ is empty or not. Any help?

Comment: local form of holomorphic function....

Comment: the local form of a holomorphic function is a power series, but they can be some coefficients equal to zero in that expansion, right?

Comment: I have answered a similar question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3784467/776794

Answer (score 1):

A bijective holomorphic function between domains is conformal and hence its derivative is never zero. The only entire function which is bijective is the polynomial of first degree. Hence its derivative is never zero.